# When to use BlockingCollection and when ConcurrentBag instead of List<T>?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, linq, task-parallel-library

The [accepted answer to the question "Why does this Parallel.ForEach code freeze the program up?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8365614/2031316) advises to substitute the List usage by [ConcurrentBag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779.aspx) in a WPF application.

I'd like to understand whether a [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) can be used in this case instead?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You can indeed use a `BlockingCollection`, but there is absolutely no point in doing so.

First off, note that [`BlockingCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is a wrapper around a collection that implements [`IProducerConsumerCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287147%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Any type that implements that interface can be used as the underlying storage:

> When you create a `BlockingCollection<T>` object, you can specify not
>   only the bounded capacity but also the type of collection to use. For
>   example, you could specify a `ConcurrentQueue<T>` object for first in,
>   first out (FIFO) behavior, or a `ConcurrentStack<T>` object for last
>   in,first out (LIFO) behavior. You can use any collection class that
>   implements the `IProducerConsumerCollection<T>` interface. The default
>   collection type for `BlockingCollection<T>` is `ConcurrentQueue<T>`.

This includes `ConcurrentBag<T>`, which means you can have a blocking concurrent bag. So what's the difference between a plain `IProducerConsumerCollection<T>` and a blocking collection? The documentation of `BlockingCollection` says (emphasis mine):

> `BlockingCollection<T>` is used as a wrapper for an
>   `IProducerConsumerCollection<T>` instance, **allowing removal attempts
>   from the collection to block until data is available to be removed**.
>   Similarly, a `BlockingCollection<T>` can be created to **enforce an
>   upper-bound on the number of data elements allowed** in the
>   `IProducerConsumerCollection<T>` [...]

Since in the linked question there is no need to do either of these things, using `BlockingCollection` simply adds a layer of functionality that goes unused.

Comment: @ Jon, thanks, this helped me a lot to break me from the state of idiocy and stop loosing time studying ConcurrentBag and BlockingCollection when I really need ConcurrentDictionary

Answer (score 36):

- `List<T>` is a collection designed to use in single thread
  applications.
- `ConcurrentBag<T>` is a class of `Collections.Concurrent` namespace designed
  to    simplify using collections in multi-thread environments. If you
  use    `ConcurrentCollection<T>` you will not have to lock your
  collection to    prevent corruption by other threads. You can insert
  or take data from your collection with no need to write special locking codes.
- `BlockingCollection<T>` is designed to get rid of the requirement of checking if new data is available in the shared collection between threads. if there is new data inserted into the shared collection then your consumer thread will awake immediately. So you do not have to check if new data is available for consumer thread in certain time intervals typically in a while loop.

Comment: I see no class for `ConcurrentCollection<T>`
From the decompiler: public class ConcurrentBag<T> : IProducerConsumerCollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable, ICollection, IReadOnlyCollection<T>

Comment: I still gave +1 - it helped to have the clarification on the consumer thread awakening on BlockingCollection<T> Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Ahmet Arslan,

Thank you for sharing great knowledge, I also want use Blocking collection coz  I do not want to check if new data is available for consumer thread in certain time intervals typically in a while loop, but I am not getting how to implement it. Can you please help me with some code snippet?

Answer (score 22):

Whenever you find the need for a thread-safe `List<T>`, in most cases neither the `ConcurrentBag<T>` nor the `BlockingCollection<T>` are going to be your best option. Both collections are specialized for facilitating producer-consumer scenarios, so unless you have more than one threads that are concurrently adding **and** removing items from the collection, you should look for other options (with the best candidate being the [`ConcurrentQueue<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1) in most cases).

Regarding especially the [`ConcurrentBag<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentbag-1), it's an extremely specialized class targeting **mixed** producer-consumer scenarios. This means that each worker-thread is expected to be both a producer and a consumer (that adds **and** removes items from the same collection). It *could* be a good candidate for the internal storage of an [`ObjectPool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/how-to-create-an-object-pool) class, but beyond that it is hard to imagine any advantageous usage scenario for this class.

People usually think that the `ConcurrentBag<T>` is the thread-safe equivalent of a `List<T>`, but it's not. The similarity of the two APIs is misleading. Calling `Add` on a `List<T>` results in adding an item at the end of the list. Calling [`Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentbag-1.add) on a `ConcurrentBag<T>` results instead in the item being added at a random slot inside the bag. The `ConcurrentBag<T>` is essentially unordered. It is [not optimized](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/14835) for being enumerated, and does a lousy job when it is commanded to do so. It maintains internally a bunch of thread-local queues, so the order of its contents is dominated by which thread did what, not by when did something happened. Before each enumeration of the `ConcurrentBag<T>`, all these thread-local queues are copied to an array, adding pressure to the garbage collector ([source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v8.0.0/src/libraries/System.Collections.Concurrent/src/System/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentBag.cs#L462)). So for example the line `var item = bag.First();` results in a copy of the whole collection, for returning just one element.

These characteristics make the `ConcurrentBag<T>` a less than ideal choice for storing the results of a `Parallel.For`/`Parallel.ForEach` loop.

A better thread-safe substitute of the `List<T>.Add` is the [`ConcurrentQueue<T>.Enqueue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1.enqueue) method. *"Enqueue"* is a less familiar word than *"Add"*, but it actually does what you expect it to do.

There is nothing that a `ConcurrentBag<T>` can do that a `ConcurrentQueue<T>` can't. For example neither collection offers a way to [remove a specific item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029818/how-to-remove-a-single-specific-object-from-a-concurrentbag) from the collection. If you want a concurrent collection with a `TryRemove` method that has a `key` parameter, you could look at the [`ConcurrentDictionary<K,V>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.tryremove) class.

The `ConcurrentBag<T>` appears frequently in the Task Parallel Library-related examples in Microsoft's documentation. Like [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-foreach-loop#example) for example. Whoever wrote the documentation, apparently they valued more the tiny usability advantage of writing `Add` instead of `Enqueue`, than the behavioral/performance disadvantage of using the wrong collection. This makes some sense considering that the examples were authored at a time when the TPL was new, and the goal was the fast adoption of the library by developers who were mostly unfamiliar with parallel programming. I get it, `Enqueue` is a scary word when you see it for the first time. Unfortunately now there is a whole generation of developers that have incorporated the `ConcurrentBag<T>` in their mental tools, although it has no business being there, considering how specialized this collection is.

In case you want to collect the results of a [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach) loop in exactly the same order as the source elements, you can use a `List<T>` protected with a `lock`. If the work inside the loop is chunky, the overhead will be negligible. An example is shown below:

```
List<TResult> results = new();

Parallel.ForEach(source, parallelOptions, (item, state, index) =>
{
    TResult result = GetResult(item); // The GetResult should do significant work
    lock (results)
    {
        while (results.Count <= index) results.Add(default);
        results[(int)index] = result;
    }
});
```

This is for the case that the `source` is a deferred sequence with unknown size. If you know its size beforehand, it is even simpler. Just preallocate a `TResult[]` array, and update it in parallel without locking:

```
TResult[] results = new TResult[source.Count];

Parallel.ForEach(source, parallelOptions, (item, state, index) =>
{
    results[index] = GetResult(item);
});
```

The TPL includes memory barriers at the end of task executions ([citation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28871878/are-you-there-asynchronously-written-value/28872058#28872058)), so after the completion of the `Parallel.ForEach` all the values of the `results` array will be visible from the current thread.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you could use `BlockingCollection` for that. `finishedProxies` would be defined as:

```
BlockingCollection<string> finishedProxies = new BlockingCollection<string>();
```

and to add an item, you would write:

```
finishedProxies.Add(checkResult);
```

And when it's done, you could create a list from the contents.

Comment: Jim Mischel, reading your [.NET Reference Guide](http://www.informit.com/guides/guide.aspx?g=dotnet). I wish I could find it earlier, so close to my practical needs