# Can I use a normal foreach on a ConcurrentBag<Τ>?

Tags: c#, multithreading, foreach, parallel.foreach, concurrent-collections

In a parallel section of my code, I save the results from each thread to a `ConcurrentBag<Τ>`.  However, when this is complete, I need to iterate through each of these results and run them through my evaluation algorithm.  Will a normal `foreach` actually iterate through all members, or do I need special code?  I've also thought about using something like a queue instead of a bag, but I don't know which would be best.  The bag will typically contain only 20 or so items at the end of the parallel code.

I.e, will actually access and run `foreach` for ALL members of the `ConcurrentBag<Τ>`?

```
ConcurrentBag<Future> futures = new ConcurrentBag<Future>();
foreach (var move in futures)
{
    // stuff
}
```

Comment: As it is IEnumerable you should be able to use foreach on ConcurrentBag

Comment: I added example code.  I'm asking because with a ConcurrentBag there's no guarantee your items come out in any particular order.

Comment: I also need to see code where you populate this concurrent bag....and concurrentbag is populated already by the threads? or you are planning to do foreach while other threads are still updating ConcurrentBag?

Comment: Concurrent bag will be looked through after it's populated.  Only a single thread will be touching it at this point.

Comment: Related: [What is the correct usage of ConcurrentBag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521584/what-is-the-correct-usage-of-concurrentbag) This might also be relevant: [ConcurrentBag TryTake method, which item is removed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45809607/concurrentbag-trytake-method-which-item-is-removed)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You don't need special code, the C#'s foreach will call "GetEnumerator" [which gives you a snapshot](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd381956(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The items enumerated represent a moment-in-time snapshot of the
>   contents of the bag. It does not reflect any update to the collection
>   after GetEnumerator was called.

Answer (score 2):

You can use normal ForEach on ConcurrentBag, but it wont produce any performance impact.

This is similar like using ForEach on List.

For better performace use Parallel.Foreach on ConcurrentBag.

```
Parallel.ForEach(futures,move=> doOperation;);
```

Use ConcurrentBag, only if u want to perform multithreaded operations.

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach()` does not magically give you better performance. In quite common cases, `Parallel.ForEach()` is actually much slower than `foreach`.

Comment: Parallel.ForEach will be fast if u are using large data

Comment: I would like to read some documentation about this. For now, I will try an ordinary foreach as snapshot is good enough in my simpler use-case.