# Add items to ConcurrentBag by multithreading

Tags: c#, multithreading, list

I'm trying to add multiple values to a ConcurrentBag, but no values actually get inside. At first I tried using List, but that apparently isn't "Thread-Safe", so I searched around and it seems like people suggest using ConcurrentBag. I tried using Thread.Sleep(100) with List and that worked, but it's slower. How can I properly add values? The debuger always shows "Count:0". Here's my code:

```
 foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in test_Words)
            {
                Form1.fr.progressBar1.Value++;
                new Thread(delegate () {
                    switch (test_Type)
                    {
                        case "Definitions":
                            bagOfExercises.Add(Read(Definitions.get(entry.Value, entry.Key)));
                            break;
                        case "Examples":
                            bagOfExercises.Add(Read(Examples.get(entry.Value, entry.Key)).Replace(entry.Key, new string('_', entry.Key.Length)));
                            break;
                    }
                }).Start();           
            }
```

Comment: What is the value of `test_Type`? If you put breakpoints on the `bagOfExercises.Add` lines do they get hit? If you put breakpoints on the `break;` lines do they get hit?

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: Kevin, I'm asking how do I properly add values to the bag. test_Type is a string. No values get added to the bag when debugging, it just stays at 0.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the correct usage of ConcurrentBag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521584/what-is-the-correct-usage-of-concurrentbag)

Comment: What does your `Read` method do and why do you need multithreading?

Comment: @nvoigt The Read method just returns a string after formatting it https://hastebin.com/eqorigedad.cs (reads every other line) and multithreading makes the program much faster - it can send multiple API requests at the same time, instead of one by one. To orhtej2 I've seen that thread, I tried Parrarel.ForEach and it's slower than what I currently have. Locking a List<T> also isn't a good option, as that also hurts performance.

Comment: You are starting a thread for each entry... and then you don't wait for any of them to finish. No wonder it's super fast right now and you don't get results. I'd say give `Parallel.ForEach` another try

Comment: @nvoigt why would I have to wait for them to finish? Isn't the point to use them at the same time? It's just that with List<T> you can't fill it from multiple threads, unlike ConcurrentBag<T>, which is thread safe, but It doesn't seem like that is the proper way to add items to it.

Comment: If you don't wait for them to finish... you won't get results. I never said you should wait for each one sequentially, but at one point you will have to wait for *all* of them. If you don't... you don't have results. Again: threading is kinda hard, I'd suggest you give `Parallel.ForEach` another try. Or maybe even `.AsParallel()` from PLinq. That's a lot easier than handling threads yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Example for PLinq:

```
Func<KeyValuePair<string, string>, string> get;

if(test_Type == "Definitions") 
{
    get = kvp => Read(Definitions.get(kvp.Value, kvp.Key));
}
else
{
    get = kvp => Read(Examples.get(kvp.Value, kvp.Key)).Replace(entry.Key, new string('_', kvp.Key.Length)));
}

var results = test_Words.AsParallel()
                        .WithDegreeOfParallelism(test_Words.Count())
                        .Select(get)
                        .ToList();
```

This tries to use one thread per entry. Normally, PLinq will decide what is the best use of resources, but in this case we know something PLinq cannot know: we wait a lot on external resources, this can be done massively parallel.