# Parallel.ForEach in Web API

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-core, thread-safety, parallel.foreach

Does the following code run without any problems or side effects?

```
var result = new List<MyTpe>();
Parallel.ForEach(items, i =>
{
   // make DB-request 
   ..
   result.Add(otherResult);
}
```

I'm not using a Dictionary, so I do not have any duplicate keys. I just add entries to the List. So, I don't need to use a concurrent collection, do I?

Comment: This should work, but the devil is in the details. Can you share how you are interacting with your database and what is in the DB request? At first impression, batching the requests into a single call would be a better path forward.

Comment: The List<T> class is not designed to be accessed by multiple threads simultaneously. Use `ConcurrentBag`

Comment: @AVTUNEY no, [don't use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521584/what-is-the-correct-usage-of-concurrentbag/75343790#75343790) a `ConcurrentBag<T>` for storing the results of a `Parallel.ForEach` loop.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias why not?

Comment: Love Coding it is not well suited for this role, resulting in bad behavior and poor performance. Click [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521584/what-is-the-correct-usage-of-concurrentbag/75343790#75343790) to read my arguments in details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not thread safe, so, yes, there could be problems such as overwriting list entries. Also, `Add` could cause the list to resize. Imagine if two threads simultaneously triggered that.

You can place a `lock` around your accesses to the list, or even better use a concurrent collection such as [ConcurrentBag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentbag-1?view=net-7.0) if you don't care about order.

Another way to do this is to allocate an array sized to the degree of parallelism on the `Parallel.ForEach` and then (safely) put the results into the respective slot. Finally, you'd then assemble the results after the loop.

Something like

```cs
// this example assumes parallelism is 4
var result = new List<MyTpe>[4];
Parallel.ForEach(items, i =>
{
   var localResult = new List<MyType>();
   // make DB-request 
   localResult.Add(otherResult);
   ...
   // n passed in somehow (check the overloads of ForEach()
   result[n] = localResult;
}

...
var finalResult = new List<MyType>();
foreach (var r in result)
    finalResult.AddRange(r);
```