# Use Parallel.ForEach with DataTable throws object reference exception

Tags: c#, datatable, parallel.foreach

i have got this code in my project. it does some cpu processing so in order to speedup stuff am trying to use Parallel.ForEach.

For some reason parallel execution adds a null item which results in "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" exception at later stage of the program.

** It shouldnt been adding null

**Working code**

```
foreach (DataRow datarow in dataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
{    
   var item = new T();

   for (int i = 0; i < datarow.Table.Columns.Count; i++)
   {
      var columnName = datarow.Table.Columns[i].ColumnName;
      var columnValue = datarow[i];
      // set new object values
      // use reflection logic to grab values
   }

   finalList.add(item);
}
```

**Error Code**

```
List<DataRow> list = dataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().ToList();

Parallel.ForEach<DataRow>(list, datarow =>
{    
   var item = new T();

   for (int i = 0; i < datarow.Table.Columns.Count; i++)
   {
      var columnName = datarow.Table.Columns[i].ColumnName;
      var columnValue = datarow[i];
      // set new object values
      // use reflection logic to grab values
   }

   finalList.add(item);
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `finalList`? If it's not one that can be modified concurrently by multiple threads you could see unexpected behaviour...

Comment: var list = new List<T>(); it feels like stuff are getting mixed up

Comment: Unless `finalList` is thread safe, you will need to wrap it with a synchronisation lock.

Comment: so add() is not thread safe?

Comment: we don't know, you did not yet tell what `finalList` is, so we can't tell if it's thread safe. if it's `List<T>`, it's not thread safe, which may lead to unexpected behaviour. Where is the exception thrown?

Comment: yeah sorry finalList is a normal list. List<T>(). this is the error.

Comment: i will use a ConcurrentBag instead

Comment: In the code that works you iterate over `dataSet.Tables[0].Rows`, however in your non-working code you iterate over `dataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().ToList()`. You could be iterating over too much because there is no `.Rows` in the second example.

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer this, this code is using a non-threadsafe collection, `List<>`, , for `FinalList`, which is inaccessible by the parallel task code.  They should use a threadsafe collection, like `ConcurrentBag` as the collection type instead.

A list of threadsafe collections can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent?view=net-6.0).

Comment: The `ConcurrentBag<T>` appears frequently in the examples in Microsoft's documentation, presumably because it has a method with the familiar name `Add`, but [it's not the best](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64823123/11178549 "When to use BlockingCollection and when ConcurrentBag instead of List<T>?") collection for the job. A better alternative is the `ConcurrentQueue<T>`, because it preserves the order of the enqueued items.