# Can one remove if in taking a reference in C#?

Tags: c#, if-statement, concurrency

I have a simple if in a hot member accessed from multiple threads.

```
if (boolFlag)
{
    Interlocked.Decrement(ref SomeCount);
}
```

If C++ were to remove this `if` case, we would probably multiply reference by flag to get null ptr or actual reference.

Is there some optimisation that would allow similar thing it C#?

Comment: No. The JIT Compiler might be able to perform such optimizations in some cases, but not in this as `Interlocked.Decrement` cannot handle a null pointer.

Comment: So one idea would be to use a Counter modifier thread in combination with `ConcurrentBag.Add(boolFlag)` in the hot path... Bot would such add actually be faster than if test?

Comment: Most probably the if will be faster than any such complex constructs. If it really matters: implement both and then measure.

Comment: @DuckQueen forget about the `ConcurrentBag<T>` class. It's a [very specialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15400133/when-to-use-blockingcollection-and-when-concurrentbag-instead-of-listt/64823123#64823123) collection. It's unlikely that you'll find a good use for this class, ever.