# Parallel.ForEach returning same fileObject twice

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

I'm trying to read a VERY large number of files from AWSS3 storage.  No issues with reading them etc.  But every now and again I get two threads with the SAME fileObject?

I've tried keeping a `List<string>` or a `ConcurrentBag<string>` of files I've processed but as the two threads hit at the same time - both think they are the first and still get the same duplication.

Any ideas how I could work around or prevent this?

```
List<S3Object> fileObjects = listFilesResponse.Result.S3Objects;
filecount += listFilesResponse.Result.KeyCount;

ParallelOptions paralleOpts = new ParallelOptions
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount
};

Parallel.ForEach(fileObjects, paralleOpts, fileObject =>
{
    fileRequest.Key = fileObject.Key;

    using (var fileResponse = s3Client.GetObjectAsync(fileRequest))
    using (Stream responseStream = fileResponse.Result.ResponseStream)
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
    {
        //do stuff with file...
    }
});
```

Comment: You mean in `//do stuff with file` you get the same file twice? If that's the case, the issue is not with `Parallel.ForEach` but how the `fileObjects` list is filled (ie it contains the same key twice). Is the `fileObjects` list manipulated (elements removed, added, ...) in any way (also by other threads), while `Parallel.ForEach` is working?

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach` doesn't return anything. It's definitely *not* meant for asynchronous or IO calls either, only for data parallelism, ie processing lots of in-memory data by partitioning and using all cores to process the partitions

Comment: Could you edit the question and include the code that interacts with the `ConcurrentBag<string>`?

Comment: The problems are in the missing code. Using a global `fileRequest.Key` from multiple threads *guarantees* duplicate requests. `List<>` isn't thread-safe either. Don't try to reuse requests, don't block the asynchronous operations. Make the entire method asynchronous and use `Parallel.ForEachAsync` instead.

Answer (score 0):

`Parallel.ForEach` doesn't return anything. It's definitely not meant for asynchronous or IO calls either, only for data parallelism, ie processing lots of in-memory data by partitioning and using all cores to process the partitions.

The first big problem is using a global variable, `fileRequest`, for the request of *all* objects. Threads will overwrite each other's changes and can easily end up making the same request.

`List<T>` isn't thread-safe either,so the modifications made to it by `Parallel.ForEach` threads will result either in concurrency exceptions or bad data.

The code needs a bit of fixing:

- A new request object should be created each time
- AWS methods are asynchronous, so the method should be asynchronous as well. Blocking the asynchronous methods will only cause problems.
- Instead of `Parallel.ForEach`, use `Parallel.ForEachAsync`. That method *is* meant for asynchronous operations. It still doesn't return any results.
- Store the data in a concurrent collection like ConcurrentQueue<> or ConcurrentDictionary<>. ConcurrentBag is a specialized collection, meant for thread-local storage.

```
async Task<ConcurrentQueue<ResultDTO>> MyDownloaderAsync()
{
    var results=new ConcurrentQueue<ResultDTO>();
    ...
    var fileObjects= await client.ListObjectsV2Async(request);

    await Parallel.ForEach(fileObjects, async (fileObject,_) =>{
        var fileRequest = new GetObjectRequest
        {
            BucketName = bucketName,
            Key = fileObject.Key;
        };

        using var fileResponse = await s3Client.GetObjectAsync(fileRequest);
        using var reader = new StreamReader(fileResponse.ResponseStream);
        //do stuff with file...
        // Create a `result` object
        results.Enqueue(result);
    }
    return results;
});
```

Comment: Assuming the order is not relevant. What exactly would be the reason not to use ConcurrentBag?

Comment: @JonasH it's only meant for scenarios that need thread-local storage. A thread can read the items it created faster than the items created by other threads. That means that in the end, enumerating the results will be slow. In the question's scenario, where all the data is already available in the Action, you pay the cost for no benefit

Comment: @JonasH see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15400133/when-to-use-blockingcollection-and-when-concurrentbag-instead-of-listt/64823123#64823123 "When to use BlockingCollection and when ConcurrentBag instead of List<T>?").

Comment: Well, in my quick unscientific test, adding a bunch of items in parallel, and reading all items serially is about three times faster with ConcurrentBag than ConcurrentQueue and ConcurrentStack. This seem very reasonable to me, after all, all of them need some type of synchronization, but only ConcurrentBag can ignore item order.

Comment: @JonasH both the `ConcurrentQueue<T>` and `ConcurrentStack<T>` are mutated with `Interlocked` operations, so essentially lock-free. The `ConcurrentBag<T>` uses thread-local storage, so adding items should be super-fast too. I would argue that even if the order of the results is not important, it is still better to get the results in the correct order because it makes testing and debugging easier. In case the adding performance is of ultimate importance, using a simple array should be faster than anything else (`results[index] = result`).