# C# Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting is not waiting for Parallel.For

Tags: c#, parallel.for

I tried a very simple test with `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting` with the following code snippet:

```
var code = @"
var myList = new List<string>();
Parallel.For(0, 300, i  =>
{
    myList.Add("""" + i);
});
return myList;";

var scrOptions = ScriptOptions.Default
    .WithReferences("System", "System.Threading", "ScriptEngineTest")
    .WithImports("System", "System.Threading.Tasks", "System.Collections.Generic")
    .WithLanguageVersion(LanguageVersion.Latest);

var script = CSharpScript.Create<List<string>>(code, scrOptions);
script.Compile();
var myList = (await script.RunAsync()).ReturnValue;
```

The code is executed fine but not waiting until the Paralell.For has finished - my return list has different counts, but not the full 300 items.

Is this a bug or maybe not really supported?

THX in advance

Comment: `List<>` is not thread safe, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-8.0#thread-safety

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The code is executed fine but not waiting until the Paralell.For has finished - my return list has different counts, but not the full 300 items.

This does not prove that `Paralell.For` is not finished. `List<T>` is not thread-safe and you see the standard [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#In_software) effect. Use [thread-safe collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/) or wrap the collection modification into [`lock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/lock).

See also:

- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64823123/2501279) for "When to use `BlockingCollection` and when `ConcurrentBag` instead of `List<T>`?"